# corda CENM networkmap server start failing to connect database after a few week run

Tags: corda

we operate CENM(1.2 and use helm template to run on k8s cluster) to construct our own private network and keep on running CENM network map server for a few week, then launching new node start failing.

with further investigation, its appeared that request timeout for http://nmap:10000/network-map causes problem.

in nmap server’s log, we found following output when access to above url with curl.

```
[NMServer] - Error while handling socket client message com.r3.enm.servicesapi.networkmap.handlers.LatestUnsignedNetworkParametersRetrievalMessage@760c53ea: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
```

`netstat` shows there is at least 3 establish connection to the database from the container which network map server runs, also I can connect database directly with using CLI.

so I don’t think it is neither database saturated nor network configuration problem.

anyone have an idea why this happens? I think restart probably solve the problem, but want to know the root cause...

regards,

Comment: Hi could you provide us with some more additional info 1. full logs for network map and other CENM components (identity manager etc), 
2.nodes on the cluster at the time of the error including the one with the connectivity issues 
3.full Kubernetes logs at the rough time window of the issue
4. information about the network topology / hosts comprising the network

Answer (score 0):

Please test the following options.

Since it is the HikariCP (connection pool) component that is throwing the error it would be worth seeing if increasing the pool size in the network map configuration may help - see below)

Corda uses Hikari Pool for creating the connection pool. To configure the connection pool any custom properties can be set in the dataSourceProperties section.

```
dataSourceProperties = {
    dataSourceClassName = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
    ...
    maximumPoolSize = 10
    connectionTimeout = 50000
}
```

Has a healthcheck been conducted to verify there are sufficient resources on that postgres database i.e basic diagnostic checks ?

Another option to get more information logged from the network map service is to run with TRACE logging also:

From https://docs.corda.net/docs/cenm/1.2/troubleshooting-common-issues.html

**Enabling debug/trace logging**

Each service can be configured to run with a deeper log level via command line flags passed at startup:

```
java -DdefaultLogLevel=TRACE -DconsoleLogLevel=TRACE -jar <enm-service-jar>.jar --config-fi
```

Comment: thanks, I have added logging configuration, if things come again, i'm going to post here